# Not able to run GHUnit test from command line

Tags: ios, gh-unit

I am trying to run GHUnitTest cases from command line.
Following all steps from [Here](http://gabriel.github.io/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_command_line.html)

My GHUnitTest target name is `GHUnitTests`. And I using following script on command line

```
default: 

\# Set default make action here

\# xcodebuild -target GHUnitTests -configuration MyMainTarget -sdk iphonesimulator build
clean:
-rm -rf build/* 
test:  GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild -target GHUnitTests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator build`
```

Runnig it using `$ make test` on terminal.
But getting the following error always.

> make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.>

How to fix it.
Plz help

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably just running "make test" from the wrong directory.

The first step to getting 'make test' to work is to be in your project directory, next to your Makefile.

Your makefile should look something like this (which I see it does in your example):
https://github.com/gh-unit/gh-unit/blob/master/Project-iOS/Makefile.example

If your project directory is `~/ios/app/MyApp/`,
then you should have saved the Makefile to `~/ios/app/MyApp/Makefile`
then

```
cd ~/ios/app/MyApp
```

then

```
make test
```